# Force RecyclerView Scroll when focus change (Android TV)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

When using RecyclerView, if all items are visible on the screen, moving focus won't cause LayoutManager to scroll.

For example:

| (1) 2 3 4 5 | -> DPAD right -> | 1 (2) 3 4 5 |

I would like to make it scroll as the focus item changed.

| (1) 2 3 4 5 | -> DPAD Right -> | (2) 3 4 5   |

I am thinking about using smoothScrollToPosition, but it wouldn't work because the layout manager doesn't consider scrolling in that situation. Is there any other way to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use VerticalGridView or HorizontalGridView from androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0 library.

```
    gridView.setItemAlignmentOffset(0)
    gridView.setItemAlignmentOffsetPercent(
        VerticalGridView.ITEM_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
    )

    // align to a fixed position from top
    gridView.setWindowAlignmentOffset(10)
    gridView.setWindowAlignmentOffsetPercent(
        VerticalGridView.WINDOW_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
    )
    gridView.setWindowAlignment(VerticalGridView.WINDOW_ALIGN_NO_EDGE)
```

This code sample is from the BaseRowFragment of the leanback library. As you can see VerticalGridView is based on RecyclerView and uses a leanback GridLayoutManager.